# Figuring out the bias of a coin based on two unknown flips

Tags: probability

Suppose you have three biased coins.  You don’t know the direction or extent of any of their biases.  You witness someone doing two coin flips. Either they flip coin 1 and then coin 3, or they flip coin 2 and then coin 1.  But you don’t know which sequence they did.  Based on the outcomes of the two coin flips, is there any way to guess the direction of the bias of coin 1 with greater than 50% probability?

This came up in the context of writing a cryptography proof.

Comment: The naive approach would be to guess the bias of the first coin is in the direction of the common result of the two flips if there is one, and to guess at random if the two flips are different.   But this approach can be undermined if for example the the first coin has probability $60\%$ of being heads while the second and third have probabilities of $10\%$ each of being heads.

Comment: Is there no approach that will give a greater than 50% chance of guessing right regardless of the biases of the three coins?